# EF: building IIncludeableQueryable dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have GET{id} with options to include relationships.

I want to do something like this:

```
        var account = _context.Accounts.Where(a => a.AccountId == id);
        if (withActiveSubscription)
        {
            account = account.Include(a => a.ActiveSubscription);
            if (withCharges)
            {
                account = account.ThenInclude(s => s.Charges);
            }
        }
```

But I get "Cannot resolve symbol 'ThenInclude' " .
I can fix that by change it to

```
            if (withCharges)
            {
                account = account.Include(a => a.ActiveSubscription).ThenInclude(s => s.Charges);
            }
```

But it's look bad, since I duplicate `account.Include(a => a.ActiveSubscription)`. 
So, How should I code this?
(I'm using EF-core)
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ThenInclude` is made available as an extension method for the type that's returned by `.Include(...)`. That type is not simply `IQueryable<T>`, and by assigning to `account`, you strip away the compile-time knowledge of extra functionality. To keep it, store it in an extra helper variable, which can have a different type from `account`:

```
var account = _context.Accounts.Where(a => a.AccountId == id);
if (withActiveSubscription)
{
    var accountAS = account.Include(a => a.ActiveSubscription);
    account = accountAS;

    if (withCharges)
    {
        var accountASC = accountAS.ThenInclude(s => s.Charges);
        account = accountASC;
    }
}
```